# Mathematically calculating unique combinations given 4 Groups of overlapping Values

Tags: statistics, combinations

I have the following Data Set:

(Group 1) A, B, C

(Group 2) A, B, C

(Group 3) A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H

(Group 4) A, B, C, D, E, F, G, H

I am chasing the mathematical formula to find out the maximum amount of unique combinations when 1 is picked from each group. The output is (group 1, group 2 , group 3, group 4). Order doesn't matter but each letter can only be used once (eg A ,A, B, C is not counted as unique) and for the unique count I want to only include where all 4 must be unique eg. A, B, C, D and A, C, B, D are the same and would only count as 1 unique outcome.

Any help would be amazing

Comment: Does it matter if an A in, e. g., "ABC", comes from Group 1 or group 2, i. e., are these two different combinations "A(1)B(1)C(1)" "A(2)B(1)C(1)" or are they the same combination?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by combination? What is the significance of the groups? Can a combination have only one element, e.g. {E}? Does {E} count as only one combination, or as two because it can be taken from two groups?

Comment: @user7427029 The output has to be 1 for each group (Group 1 , Group 2 , Group 3 , Group 4) It does not matter what order however the end result must be unique. e.g (B, A, F, G and B, A, G, F) would be classified as duplicates.

Comment: @Jaap Scherphuis. Each letter refers to a material. The first 2 slots can only be 1 of 3 types of materials whereas the next 2 slots can be 8 types of materials (which include the materials used in the first 2 slots. The only rule is that. The output can't have duplicates eg. A A B C all have to be unique. Working out perms (3*2*16*15) =1440 but this includes the answer A, B ,C ,E and A, B, E, C which is a output duplicate. The answer should be around 330 unique worked out by brute force but can't work out how to do it mathematically. (Actual problem has 18 in group 3 and 4)

Comment: So you are taking one item from each group? Please edit your question to include that.

Comment: Case 2 is what I'm after. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two cases to work out:

**Case 1:** All three letters A, B, C are chosen. Two of these will be from group 1 and 2, and one from one of the other groups, but it does not matter which one. The fourth chosen letter is one of D to H, so there are only $5$ possible combinations in this case.

**Case 2:** Exactly two of the three letters A, B, C are chosen. These must come from groups 1 and 2. The other two groups will then give two of the five letters D to H. The total number of possibilities is $\binom{3}{2}\binom{5}{2} = \frac{3\cdot2}{2} \cdot \frac{5\cdot4}{2}= 3\cdot10=30$.

In total we get $5+30=35$ combinations.

If the large groups have $18$ items, then the number of combinations is $15 + \binom{3}{2}\binom{15}{2} = 15 + \frac{3\cdot2}{2} \cdot \frac{15\cdot14}{2} = 15 + 3\cdot105=330$.